# What should ",7-6-5-4-3-2-1,".split(',') return?

Tags: string, scala, split, scala-2.8

What should `",7-6-5-4-3-2-1,".split(',')` return?

It seems to return

```
  blank string
  7-6-5-4-3-2-1
```

ie. two strings. I'd expect either one or three strings - that is a blank string at both ends or just the string between ','s.

Am I wrong? Is there a good explanation for the current behaviour?

EDIT:

OK. So yes, I had the wrong expectation and no, there is no good explanation other than Java works that way :). Thanks.

EDIT2:

You can get the desired behaviour with `split(",", -1)`
(Scala 2.8.1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how it works. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), which explains Java's regex version of it, but it's the same thing in the end:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Comment: Note that you can cause trailing empty strings to be included using `s.split(",", -1)`

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour is expecteded. `String#split(Char)` ultimately (via `StringLike#split(Char)` and `String#split(String)`) calls the Java `String#split(String, 0)` which is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> [...] the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded

**Edit** - If you want more control over splitting strings, look at `Splitter` in the [Guava libraries](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

```
Splitter.on(',').split(",7-6-5-4-3-2-1,")
```